# how to build progress bar based on categary?

Tags: angularjs

I've 3 categories and each category is having 3 questions each. If a user starts category-1 and finished it, I need to show 33.33% progress status in progress bar. Then when category 2 is finished show 66.66% progress bar status and finally when the user finishes category-3 then progress will as 99.99%.

```
html
-----

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
    <div progressbar="category"></div>
     <div ng-hide="category1">
       <p><span  style="color:red">category1</span><br/>
           <span>question1</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp1" value="yes" ng-model="user.q1" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp1" value="no" ng-model="user.q1" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question2</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp2" value="yes" ng-model="user.q2" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp2" value="no" ng-model="user.q2" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question3</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp3" value="yes" ng-model="user.q3" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp3" value="no" ng-model="user.q3" />
       </p>
       <button ng-click="catg1()">1 Next</button>
      </div><!-- category1 closed-->
     <div ng-show="category2">
       <p><span style="color:red">category2</span><br/>
           <span>question4</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp4" value="yes" ng-model="user.q4" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp4" value="no" ng-model="user.q4" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question5</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp5" value="yes" ng-model="user.q5" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp5" value="no" ng-model="user.q5" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question6</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp6" value="yes" ng-model="user.q6" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp6" value="no" ng-model="user.q6" />
       </p>
       <button ng-click="catg2()">2 Next</button>
     </div><!-- category2 closed-->
     <div ng-show="category3">
       <p><span style="color:red">category3</span><br/>
           <span>question7</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp7" value="yes" ng-model="user.q7" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp7" value="no" ng-model="user.q7" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question8</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp8" value="yes" ng-model="user.q8" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp8" value="no" ng-model="user.q8" />
       </p><p>
           <span>question9</span>
           <input type = "radio" name="grp6" value="yes" ng-model="user.q9" />
           <input type = "radio" name="grp6" value="no" ng-model="user.q9" />
       </p>
       <button ng-click="catg3()">3 Next</button>
     </div><!-- category3 closed-->
</div>

script
------
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.category1 = false;
  $scope.category2 = false;
  $scope.category3 = false;
    $scope.catg1 = function(){
  $scope.category1 = true;
  $scope.category2 = true;
  $scope.category3 = false;
  }
  $scope.catg2 = function(){
        $scope.category1 = true;
  $scope.category2 = false;
  $scope.category3 = true;
  }
  $scope.catg3 = function(){
        $scope.category1 = true;
  $scope.category2 = false;
  $scope.category3 = false;
  }
    $scope.items = [0, 33.33, 66.66, 99.99, 0]
}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=progressbar'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.progressbar({
                value: $scope.progress
            })

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                $element.progressbar({value: $scope.progress})
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A2CV5/629/

Comment: please help me any one please

Comment: You are changing category 1, 2 and 3 when the user completes the questions. So you could simply set a value of percentage like `$scope.perc` to each function and pass that value to progress bar directive. Try. and get back here with your output.

Comment: $scope.perc means , i am understand can you help in jsfiddle

Comment: when clicked next button it should move progress bar 33.33%, how can do please help http://jsfiddle.net/A2CV5/629/

Comment: when clicking next button you are calling a function, in that function set a scope variable to 66%. It will reflect in DOM. You try and update the fiddle and I am happy to help.

Comment: yes I  did  clicked Next button calling  a function, in that functions  set scope 33.33, 66.66, 99.99  but it still not working how can i do please help me